# Join clause incorrect on multiple join LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have a multiple join query like this:

```
public static List<Answer> GetDetailedAnswers(string Tag)
    {
        using (Database db = new Database())
        {

            List<Answer> answer = 
                         from quest in db.Question
                         join answ in db.Answer on quest.ID equals answ.QuestionID
                         join deal in db.Dealer on answ.DealerID equals deal.ID
                         join country in db.Country on deal.CountryID equals country.CountryID
                         where quest.ParentSection == Tag
                         select new 
                         { 
                                      ParentSection = quest.ParentSection, 
                                      Section = quest.Section, 
                                      Dealer = deal.Name, 
                                      OriginalAnswer = answ.Original,
                                      EngAnswer = answ.English,
                                      Region = country.Country
                         }.ToList();
            return answer;
        }
    }
```

And i have an internal class like this:

```
public class Answer
    {
        public string ParentSection { get; set; }
        public string Section { get; set; }
        public string Dealer { get; set; }
        public string OriginalAnswer { get; set; }
        public string EngAnswer { get; set; }
        public string Region { get; set; }
    }
```

I get an error on the last join. It says "the type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'" 
What did i miss? Thx

Comment: check both have same datatyope, may be one is int 2nd is long like that

Comment: I might be asking the obvious but what are the data types of the fields in the last `join`?

Comment: It was the error i suspected but i couldn't recognize why. One is uniqueID and the other is Int. Changing it the problem is solved, but now i get this error: "AnonymousType#1 does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList'". Should i make and ovveride method in the class Answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the error: "AnonymousType#1 does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList'", You can do following.

```
  public static List<Answer> GetDetailedAnswers(string Tag)
{
    using (Database db = new Database())
    {

        List<Answer> answer = 
                     (from quest in db.Question
                     join answ in db.Answer on quest.ID equals answ.QuestionID
                     join deal in db.Dealer on answ.DealerID equals deal.ID
                     join country in db.Country on deal.CountryID equals country.CountryID
                     where quest.ParentSection == Tag
                     select new Answer
                     { 
                                  ParentSection = quest.ParentSection, 
                                  Section = quest.Section, 
                                  Dealer = deal.Name, 
                                  OriginalAnswer = answ.Original,
                                  EngAnswer = answ.English,
                                  Region = country.Country
                     }).ToList();
        return answer;
    }
}
```

You need to surround you query within round brackets and then apply .ToList() method to it.

Comment: It worked, but it says i cannot convert List<AnonymousType#1> into a List<Answer>. I'm gonna figure out this. Thanks

Comment: Yes because you haven't specified Answer class in select. check my answer i had added Answer class in it. if you write select only with new that means it "AnonymousType", so it can't convert it to List<Answer>. So you need to specify type.

Comment: Yes i already solved it yesterday, i had just to read the code to get the error. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Please check the data type of

deal.CountryID and country.CountryID. this should be same